# Object-Detection-using-Fast-R-CNN python and brain_script model different?

Tags: object-detection, cntk

For the toy example A2 part of the Beta 12 Release, it is said that there are two option for training:

1. A2_RunCntk_py3.py (python API)
2. A2_RunCntk.py (brain_script)

Are the models trained from these two methods the same? Or in other words, can I load the model from brain_script into python API and then detect other testing images?

Also see [Object Detection using Fast R CNN](http://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Object-Detection-using-Fast-R-CNN).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to use Python to load a model you trained with Brainscript. A few gotchas in doing this correctly are described [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/How-do-I-Evaluate-models-in-Python#evaluate-a-saved-convolutional-network). We are working on making things work seamlessly without too much Python code for massaging the data.